# How to access C# MessageHeader Concrete types

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I receive a `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` from a WCF service, it has a message header  that at runtime is of type `System.ServiceModel.Channels.ToHeader` but I can't find this type anywhere to upcast it to use the `ToHeader`s properties.

Is this a dynamic type that can only be accessed by reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to access the members of the `ToHeader` class (which is internal). The only property which cannot be accessed from the base (public) class is the `To` (of type Uri), which you can access via the message directly (`message.Headers.To`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that when I get in on Monday.